# CSS3 animation + display property

Tags: css

I have been using the following solution to show and hide elements for a while. This solution contains a few drawbacks, like the element being manipulated having a fixed height.

```
    @keyframes hide {
        0% { height: inherit; opacity: 1; visibility: visible; }
        99% { height: inherit; opacity: 0; visibility: visible; }
        100% { height: 0; opacity: 0; visibility: hidden; }
    }

    @keyframes show {
        0% { height: 0; opacity: 0; visibility: hidden; }
        1% { height: inherit; opacity: 0; visibility: visible; }
        100% { height: inherit; opacity: 1; visibility: visible; }
    }
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xOaPvN

Is it possible to obtain the same result using the display property instead and modifying only the CSS? I tried a lot but I was not able to figure it out.

**UPDATE:**

It is not possible until it is possible, right?

```
        @keyframes hide {
            0% { display: block; opacity: 1; }
            99% { display: block; opacity: 0; }
            100% { display: none; opacity: 0; }
        }

        @keyframes show {
            0% { display: none; opacity: 0; }
            1% { display: block; opacity: 0; }
            100% { display: block; opacity: 1; }
        }
```

Comment: I know this breaks your rule of only modifying the CSS, but jQuery would save you quite a few lines of code and complexity here, especially for something this simple. http://api.jquery.com/fadein/

Comment: Please keep a professional behaviour on SO and avoid unnecessary strong language.

Comment: @Jordan jQuery is not good.

Comment: Arguably it is better than CSS in this case. I prefer leaving styling and animations to CSS as well but sometimes it's better to use JavaScript. Unless you have a specific reason I wouldn't just say it's "not good." Why can you not use it? Or why don't you want to?

Comment: @incompleteness Your element is not suppressed, it's just hidden, and that's due to `opacity`. `display` does nothing.

Comment: okay, maybe you got me there. i will recheck

Comment: @Jordan The main reason behind css animations becoming the industry golden boy is jQuery being so terrible bad. jQuery destroyed the reputation of javascript animations so badly that only now the regular programming joe is realizing that is possible to get gpu acceleration and other css animations juice using vanilla or other animation libraries. Also, recommending (or push, right?) to one a complete library with hundreds of features inside to solve a small trivial problem is just dumb.

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not possible, because `display` is not animatable.

> ### [2. Box Layout Modes: the `display` property](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#the-display-properties)
>
> *Animatable*: no

Comment: Correct if I'm wrong, the property itself cannot be animated (because it only has concrete states) but the property can be used in keyframe animations. I saw a few examples exploring this idea to hide an element.

Comment: just posted the solution. Have fun with it.

Comment: @incompleteness You can use it in the keyframes, but since `display` can't be interpolated it shouldn't do anything. Your code does not suppress the element for me.